# Temp directory using tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, temp

Is there any way to find temp directory using tcl/tk?
Similar to the one in python-->
print tempfile.gettempdir() # prints the current temporary directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular function to do that.  You can do:

```
set tmpdir {}
set tdlist {}
set dlist [list TMPDIR TEMP TMP]
foreach {d} $dlist {
  if { [info exists ::env($d)] } {
    lappend tdlist $::env($d)
  }
}
# add more locations to this list if needed
lappend tdlist C:/temp c:/tmp /tmp /var/tmp
foreach {d} $tdlist {
  if { [file exists $d] && [file isdirectory $d] } {
    set tmpdir $d
    break
  }
}
```

If you just need a temporary file, there is the `file tempfile` function that
will return a file handle to be used.

Comment: 8.7 adds `file tempdir`.